# C#: Executing multiple timers simultaneously

Tags: c#

I have three label controls and with the help of For Loop, I have written a method that moves the controls from the top of the form to the bottom. I have three timers, each move one control repeatedly, but the problem is that they execute one after another.

I want the times to execute simultaneously i.e. all the three labels move from the top of the form to the right at the same time.

NOTE: After each call of the timer, I have set up a random object that resets the position randomly on the top of the form.

Comment: What kind of timer are you using? There are several, with different semantics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then don't use three timer.Just use one timer and put your code inside of it's Tick event.

According to your code you can do the following, define your `Random` variable outside of your method,and just use `timer1_Tick` event, you can remove other timers:

```
Random random = new Random(); 
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int X = random.Next(0, 1230); 
        int y = X; 
        label2.Location = new Point(X, 5);
        label3.Location = new Point(X, 5);
        for (int i = 5; i <= 470; i++)
        {
            label2.Location = new Point(y, i);
            label3.Location = new Point(y, i);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
}
```

Comment: Here is the code for one label. When I press a button in Form, the label starts moving continuously. 
How can I start them simultaneously and if I shouldn't use the Timer, then what else? Threads etc.?

Comment: private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = "Key Pressed: " + e.KeyChar;
           //animate(sender, e);
            timer1.Start();
            timer2.Start();


        }

Comment: private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            Random random = new Random();
            int X = random.Next(0, 1230);
            int y = X;
            label2.Location = new Point(X, 5);
            for (int i = 5; i <= 470; i++)
            {
                timer2.Start();
                label2.Location = new Point(y, i);
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }

Comment: private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int X = random.Next(0, 1230);
            int y = X;
            label3.Location = new Point(X, 5);
            for (int i = 5; i <= 470; i++)
            {
                label3.Location = new Point(y, i);
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }

Comment: Okay, thank you, how do I intercept this event with key event, for example, if, during the animation, I press any key, it stops the animation or perform some action?

Comment: @user3206911 Edit your question,don't post your code like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use one timer and if you want to be fancy have the tick execute various callbacks. That way you can define at run time what should be in the tick.

Comment: Okay, thank you, how do I intercept this event with key event, for example, if, during the animation, I press any key, it stops the animation or perform some action?