# How can I avoid the difference of milliseconds between two Chronometers start time?

Tags: android, timer, chronometer

I have two Chronometer in an activity. 
First Chronometer is for elapsed time, and Second Chronometer is for interval time.

**For Ex.:-**
We chose 5 Min elapsed time and 30 Seconds interval time, now we start both timers at the same time by pressing btn_start. Both timers start with 0, now when interval timer reaches 00:30 time it restarts again with 0.

**Now the issue:-**
As I have cross checked both timers start with a difference of milliseconds. Which later becomes a difference of 1 second,2 seconds,3 seconds or more seconds.

Below is Custom Chronometer.Java

```
public class PausableChronometer extends Chronometer implements PlaybackStateView {
    // Keeps track of how far long the Chronometer has been tracking when it's paused. We'd like
    // to start from this time the next time it's resumed.
    private long timeWhenStopped = 0;

    public PausableChronometer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PausableChronometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PausableChronometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeWhenStopped);
        Log.e("start()", String.valueOf(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeWhenStopped));
        super.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        super.stop();
        timeWhenStopped = getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    }

    /**
     * Reset the timer and start counting from zero.
     */
    @Override
    public void restart() {
        reset();
        start();
    }

    public void reset() {
        stop();
        setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        timeWhenStopped = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timeWhenStopped);
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        stop();
        timeWhenStopped = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - getBase();

    }

}
```

On Button Clicked I execute following:

```
private void startTimer() {
        intervalTimer.start();
        elapsedTimer.start();
    }
```

**Please let me know, How can I avoid the difference of milliseconds between both Chronometers start time?**

Comment: Probably you can't, that's good to prevent Meltdown/Spectre vulnerabilities

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Okay so, can you please suggest how to achieve the feature that I want. and I hope the feature is clear to you after reading this post. If not then, please let me know.

Comment: That's the point, you should be unable to achieve the feature

Comment: @AntonMalyshev is that means I can't achieve this feature by whatever I try?

Comment: You have to use single timer, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187891/c-executing-multiple-timers-simultaneously

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Thanks for the link, I will have a look and try to implement it and let you know whether it works or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165744/discussion-between-pankaj-mundra-and-anton-malyshev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anton Malyshev said that it's not possible to avoid the difference of start time of two different chronometers.

I used Handler and Runnable to resolve the issue and for me, it works perfectly.

```
private TextView elapsedTimer, intervalTimer;
Handler mHandlerElapsed = new Handler(), mHandlerInterval = new Handler();
Runnable mRunnableElapsed, mRunnableInterval;
private int nCounterInterval = 0, nCounterElapsed = 0;
```

Method for timer:-

```
private void updateTime() {

        mHandlerElapsed = new Handler();
        mRunnableElapsed = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!isPause) {
                    mHandlerElapsed.postDelayed(mRunnableElapsed, 1000);
                    nCounterElapsed++;

                        elapsedTimer.setText(AppUtil.formattedTime(nCounterElapsed));                    

                } else {
                    mHandlerElapsed.removeCallbacks(mRunnableElapsed);
                }
            }
        };

        mHandlerElapsed.post(mRunnableElapsed);

        mHandlerInterval = new Handler();
        mRunnableInterval = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!isPause) {
                    mHandlerInterval.postDelayed(mRunnableInterval, 1000);
                    nCounterInterval++;
                    intervalTimer.setText(AppUtil.formattedTime(nCounterInterval));

                } else {
                    mHandlerInterval.removeCallbacks(mRunnableInterval);
                }
            }
        };
        mHandlerInterval.post(mRunnableInterval);
    }
```

for start and pause timer:-

```
private void startTimer() {
        isPause = false;
        updateTime();
    }

 private void pauseTimer() {
        isPause = true;
        updateTime();
    }
```

In AppUtil.java

```
 public static String formattedTime(int totalSeconds) {
        int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
        int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
        if (totalSeconds >= 3600) {
            minutes = minutes + 60;
        }
        return String.format(Locale.US, "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    }
```

Using the above solution my issue is resolved.